# dojox fixed="top" doesnt work, is this the right way to do it?

Tags: fixed, dojo, heading, dojox.mobile

i generate my heading with javascript but it isn't fixed on the top. Firebug shows that there is no fixed="top" in the html code.

I do it this way. This is the way to do it, isn't it?:

```
var newAlarmHeading = new dojox.mobile.Heading({
    id: "headerAlarms",
    dojoType: "dojox.mobile.Heading",
    back: "zur&uuml;ck",
    moveTo: "previousDivNode",
    fixed: "top",
    label: "Meldungen",
});
newAlarmHeading.placeAt("divAlarms",'first');
```

Comment: i figured out that this is not the right way. To add a fixed bar i have to use 'dijit.byId("divAlarms").addFixedBar(newAlarmHeading);' instead of 'newAlarmHeading.placeAt("divAlarms",'first');' but this doesnt solve it at all, after that the back button doesnt work anymore :(((

Answer (score 1):

Please see my answer to your other (related) question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16604456/1723384
In particular, you can try getting inspiration from the test file that I've pointed in my answer.

I would add that you shouldn't put the dojoType attribute into Heading's constructor argument. This is for the markup case, that is when you create your widgets declaratively in HTML. By the way, with the latest Dojo releases (starting with 1.7 if I remember well), you should use the HTML5-compatible "data-dojo-type" attribute instead of the old dojoType (see also http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/parser.html ). But, again, this is for the declarative creation of widgets, not for the programmatic creation.

Hope this helps,
Adrian